# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0 error in asp.net core 3.1 solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am working on Asp.Net Core 3.1 solution. I have an requirement where i need to add an another Asp.Net dll build in .Net Framework 2.0. When i add that dll in my core solution it builds correctly but it is giving me runtime error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue ?

Comment: .NET Core is not compatible with .NET Framework. You need to migrate .NET Framework dll to .NET Standard or .NET Core 3.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can only reference dll's compiled for .net core or .net standard (not .net framework). You will either have to recompile the dll if you own the code to target .net standard, or find a replacement if you don't.

Comment: ok i got it , it's not possible to refer the .net framework dll, but i tried changing the framework in .csproj file , it doesn't work. Do i have to rewrite the whole code in .net core or any other options is there ?

Comment: depending on what the code does and what parts of the full framework it depends on, you may need to re-write. .net standard projects use a newer csproj format, so you can't just change the target from framework to standard, you will need to create a project targeting standard, and then copy over the code/update references etc. depeneding on the complexity of the project, this can either be a quick thing or take weeks of work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is install the .net Framework 3.5 features. As you're trying to use a dll which relies on .Net Framework 2.0 (which is almost *15 years old!*), the components are not installed by default for these to run anymore. Installing the older framework [(which there is instructions on how to do here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10) should install the prerequisites for your ancient DLL to load.

*HOWEVER*, I wouldn't expect this to work too well. While you *can* use .net Framework DLLs from .Net Core, it uses the .Net Standard Compatibility Shim, which allows you to compile apps which reference older DLLs from core. It *does not* guarantee however that they will work.

As the shim is for .Net Standard, it can only target as low as .Net Framework 4.5, so *if* it does work, you should count yourself very lucky, and seek a newer version of your asp.Net 2.0 based dll. Well, you should do that anyway. There's almost no valid reason to be trying to use .net core 3 with ANCIENT assemblies built before some people on this website were even born.

Comment: Means i need to re-write the whole code in .Net Core or there is any other option